# Is possible Django CRUD operation without using model forms?

Tags: django

I am creating a Registration app in django where I want to update user info after login.
I am using bootstrap forms. Is possible Django CRUD operation without using model forms?

I created user like this:

```
def handleRegister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        email = request.POST['email']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

        # check erronous inputs
        if len(username) > 10:
            messages.error(request, "Username should be less than 10 chracters")
            return redirect('/')
        if pass1 != pass2:
            messages.error(request, "Passwords do not match")
            return redirect('/')
        if not username.isalnum():
            messages.error(request, "Username should be alphanumeric")
            return redirect('/')

        # creating user here
        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1) #creating user with the help of User(you have to import it. from django.contrib.auth.models import User)
        myuser.first_name = fname
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.save() # saving created user
        messages.success(request, "Your account has been created sucessfully")
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("404 not found")
```

is there any method like above where I can update user info?

Comment: The fact that you use a bootstrap form, does not mean you can not use a `ModelForm`. You do not *need* to render the form in HTML. A `ModelForm`, does several things: validating input, saving/updating the object in the database, and rendering the form, but you can only select a subset of the tasks.

Comment: using django forms is much complex for me

Comment: you can update the user by doing Profile.objects.get(user=request.user), define user with a onetoone relation in Profile model. In this way you can add additional info of user

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible in Django.

If you have to know (or you can use the username that you got from input field), be assure to use **primary key always**:

```
UPDATED_fname = "user fname"
UPDATED_lname = "user lname"


myuser = myuser.objects.get(id=YOUR_USER_ID) #get with id
   **OR**
myuser = myuser.objects.get(username=YOUR_username) #get with username
myuser.first_name = UPDATED_fname #update field
myuser.last_name = UPDATED_lname #update field

myuser.save() #User with that username will be updated
```